# It always mounts old share to Kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, nfs

We wanted to seperate NFS Shares for 2 envs of web application. I mount NFS share to pod in deployment yaml.

volumes:
- name: data
nfs:
path: /path/to/share
server: x.x.x.x

it always mounts the old share. When I ran mount command in pod it seems okay but it actually lsits the old share's files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify a [`volumeMounts.subPath`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath) for you to use a specific path from the NFS

```
  volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /my-nfs-data/new_share
    name: test-volume
    subPath: new_share
volumes: 
- name: 
  nfs: 
    server: x.x.x.x
    path: /nfs_shared
    readOnly: false
```

Or you can declare a [PV and PVC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistent-volumes) for other version of your deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: my-app:1.0
          name: my-app
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1234
              name: my-app
          volumeMounts:
            - name: my-pv-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/my-app
      volumes:
        - name: my-pv-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: my-app-pvc
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-app-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  volumeName: my-app-pv
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: my-app-pv
spec:
  storageClassName: ""
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  mountOptions:
    - hard
    - nfsvers=4.1
  nfs:
    path: /path/nfs_share
    server: 10.12.14.16
```